# как записать правильно в json данные

Tags: javascript, jquery

задача состоит в том чтобы каждый таб поместить в отдельный обьект(его имя и данные, для каждого), но у меня скрипт пишет всё в одно место как можно правильно это сделать, чтобы в результате было скорее всего так: `"tabs": [{name: tab 1, content: view item1}, {name: tab 2, content: какойто значение}]`
html

```
<div class="event-info-view__item" data-menu-item="event-1">
  <div class="custom-tabs__items">
    <div class="custom-tabs__item-nav active">tab 1</div>
    <div class="custom-tabs__item-nav">tab 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-tabs__view">
     <div class="custom-tabs__view-item active">view item 1</div>
     <div class="custom-tabs__view-item">view item 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event-info-view__item"  data-menu-item="event-2">
  <div class="custom-tabs__items">
    <div class="custom-tabs__item-nav">tab 6</div>
    <div class="custom-tabs__item-nav">tab 7</div>
  </div>
<div class="custom-tabs__view">
     <div class="custom-tabs__view-item active">view item 6</div>
     <div class="custom-tabs__view-item">view item 7</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="save-custom-tabs">save</button>
```

js:

```
$(".save-custom-tabs").click(function() {
            var event = [];

            $('.event-info-view__item').each(function() {
                var self = $(this),
                    tabsName = [],
                    items = self.find(".custom-tabs__items");


                items.each(function() {
                    var name = $(this).find(".custom-tabs__item-nav").text();
                    tabsName.push({
                        name: name
                    });
                });

                event.push({
                    categoryName: self.attr("data-menu-item"),
                    tabs: tabsName
                });
            });

            elements = {
                EventInfo: event
            };
            elements = JSON.stringify(elements);
            console.log(elements);
        });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы почти все сделали. Но когда проходите циклом по по `event-info-view__item`. Там по сохраните индекс `var $key = key`. А после во втором цикле каждый раз по проходе создайте подмассив `tabsName[$key]`. и сделайте `tabsName[$key].push` вместо `tabsName.push`.

```js
$(".save-custom-tabs").click(function() {
    var event = [];

    $('.event-info-view__item').each(function(key) {
        var $key = key;
        var self = $(this),
            tabsName = [],
            items = self.find(".custom-tabs__items");


        items.each(function() {
            tabsName[$key] = [];
            var name = $(this).find(".custom-tabs__item-nav").text();
            tabsName[$key].push({
                name: name
            });
        });

        event.push({
            categoryName: self.attr("data-menu-item"),
            tabs: tabsName
        });
    });

    elements = {
        EventInfo: event
    };
    //elements = JSON.stringify(elements);
    console.log(elements);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event-info-view__item" data-menu-item="event-1">
  <div class="custom-tabs__items">
    <div class="custom-tabs__item-nav active">tab 1</div>
    <div class="custom-tabs__item-nav">tab 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-tabs__view">
     <div class="custom-tabs__view-item active">view item 1</div>
     <div class="custom-tabs__view-item">view item 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="event-info-view__item"  data-menu-item="event-2">
  <div class="custom-tabs__items">
    <div class="custom-tabs__item-nav">tab 6</div>
    <div class="custom-tabs__item-nav">tab 7</div>
  </div>
<div class="custom-tabs__view">
     <div class="custom-tabs__view-item active">view item 6</div>
     <div class="custom-tabs__view-item">view item 7</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="save-custom-tabs">save</button>
```

Comment: Я пытаюсь добиться вот такого результать tabs": [{name: tab 1, content: view item1}, {name: tab 2, content: какойто значение}]

Comment: с этого таба мне нужно будет content, title и еще чтонить вытаскивать и мне нужно каждый отдельно записывать както

Comment: @DimaVleskov Ну тогда вы вопрос не так задали как нужно было